# Need to start tomcat manually

Tags: tomcat

I am having a dummy project using Jquery and REST service. I am using tomcat as the application server.  when I am hitting the context path as `<http://localhost:8082/RestfulWeb>` I am not able to see my index.html. however, when I am starting the server manually by going to the tomcat installation directory and hitting the URL again I am able to see the page. kindly help me understand why can't I just start the server from eclipse and access the url then starting it manually?

Comment: Probably because you configured the Tomcat server in eclipse to use a different configuration than the default one.

Comment: how can I solve this??

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to configure Tomcat to run from within Eclipse.  Not knowing what your config is, I'd suggest this:

1) Search your Eclipse, Tomcat, and application directories for files named `web.xml`.  You'll probably find more than one (you'll probably find at least two, and maybe more).  They'll probably have different `<welcome-file-list>`s (or one of them might not have `<welcome-file-list>` at all).

2) Edit each of the web.xml's that you find so that between `<welcome-file-list>` and `</welcome-file-list>`, there is this: `<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>`.  THe welcome-file-list element contains all files that you want to act as possible defaults to serve if a file isn't specified in the URL (other common ones are ovbiously index.jsp, index.htm, etc.; you can list as many as you want).

3) Stop Tomcat; rebuild your Eclipse project; restart Tomcat; try it out.